# Google Apps Script, calling function once when document is copied

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been playing around with Google Script Editor and I've gotten heaps of use out of it.

The next task that I am looking at is automatic formatting and text insertion/replacement when copying a **Template**.

An example use case is as follows: Within my organisation I have submitted a Doc to the template gallery. When creating a copy of the template I want it to  automatically insert today's date and the current time (rounded to the nearest hour).

This is a question about the Triggers. The text replacement bit is easy and done. Not to mention this is just one of the basic use cases, I'll be attempting many more similar behaviours with things like timesheets and the like.

The problem that I am running into is that I can't seem to get the triggers to work as I'd like them to.

2 of the Triggers that I thought I could try and use: `onOpen(e)` and `onInstall(e)`.

`onOpen(e)`, though it works, it works "too well". That is, it also replaces the text on the original template as well, proving a nuisance when updating info in these templates.

`onInstall(e)`, I thought this would work as creating a copy of the Doc also "installs" the script as well. However this function doesn't seem to run at all.

Any ideas about getting a trigger to happen once and only once when a Doc is created from a template?

Cheers,
Bricktron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Trigger `onInstall(e)` works only for Add-ons. 
Now coming to `onOpen(e)`, in my opinion you can use [Google Apps Script Property's Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to store one flag which helps your code identifying whether this file has been opened or not.

So for very first time `onOpen(e)` runs, assign property eg: `propertyService.setProperty("opened","TRUE")`  and next time you can check by accessing the property whether it has been already "opened" or not.

Example:

```
var openedFlag=propertyService.getProperty("opened");
if(openedFlag=="TRUE"){
  //Document has been modified
  //Do not run the modifiable code again
}else {
  //First time
  //Edit the file
  //Set the propertyService to "TRUE"
}
```